# Crash In Helpshift Android

Tags: android, crash, stack-trace, helpshift

I am getting following stack on after sending first message to helpshift. I am very new to android and do not understand how to debug this. Also this crash happens one in 5 times so I am not sure how to reproduce n fix it.

```
0   
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
1   
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
2   
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
3   
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
4   
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
5   
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
6   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
7   
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
8   
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
9   
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10  
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
11  
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
12  
at com.helpshift.HSApiData.updateUAToken(SourceFile:1260)
13  
at com.helpshift.Helpshift.registerDeviceToken(SourceFile:641)
14  
at notifications.GCMRegisterCheck$RegisteringHelpShiftWithToken.doInBackground(SourceFile:337)
15  
at notifications.GCMRegisterCheck$RegisteringHelpShiftWithToken.doInBackground(SourceFile:331)
16  
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
17  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
18  
... 4 more
19  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
20  
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
21  
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
22  
at com.helpshift.HSApiData.updateUAToken(SourceFile:1260)
23  
at com.helpshift.Helpshift.registerDeviceToken(SourceFile:641)
24  
at notifications.GCMRegisterCheck$RegisteringHelpShiftWithToken.doInBackground(SourceFile:337)
25  
at notifications.GCMRegisterCheck$RegisteringHelpShiftWithToken.doInBackground(SourceFile:331)
26  
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
27  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
28  
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
29  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
30  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
31  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This crash is occurring because the call is happening from a thread which does not contain an associated looper. To stop this crash :

1. Create a handler thread.
2. Use the looper of the above handler thread and create a register handler.
3. Make the API call inside the register handler.

Inside your async task -

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
   HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("register-device-token");
   handlerThread.start();
   new RegisterDeviceTokenHandler(handlerThread.getLooper(), context).post(null);
   return null;
}
```

Your register device token handler -

```
private static class RegisterDeviceTokenHandler extends Handler {

    private final Context context;

    public RegisterDeviceTokenHandler(Looper looper, Context context) {
        super(looper);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Helpshift.registerDeviceToken(context, "hello");
    }
}
```

For any other queries, feel free to contact us at support@helpshift.com